# Moving matrix from c++ to Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, import, matrix

I'm trying to take a matrix from c++ and import it to Matlab to run bintprog on this matrix, call it m. My c++ code generates these matrices of a certain type, and I need to run bintprog on them quickly, and with ideally millions of matrices.

So any of the following would be great:
A way to import a bunch of matrices at once so I can run a lot of iterations thru my Matlab code. 
Or
If I could implement Matlab code right in c++ nicely.

If this is not clear leave me comments and I'll update what I can.

Comment: You could just call Matlab from C++ -- http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-c-c-and-fortran-programs.html

Answer (score 1):

You can call Matlab commands from C++ code (and vice  versa):

1. Compile your C++ code into a `mex` function and call `bintprog` using [`mexCallMatlab`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexcallmatlab.html).
2. As proposed by Mark, you may call Matlab engine from native C++ code using [matlab engine](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-c-c-and-fortran-programs.html).
3. You may compile your C++ code as a shared library and call it from Matlab using [`calllib`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-c-c-and-fortran-programs.html).

Comment: I've looked at #2, and see to include engine.h, but I have no idea where that file may be? Any knowledge? I'm running this on OSX 10.7

Comment: @KevinShaffer Isn't it in `matlabroot/extern/include` ?

Comment: It is, i just found it, but when I try to include it I get an error saying the file doesn't exist.
This is the directory it is in, where applications is on my drive called "Solid State"
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a/extern/include/engine.h
So in full I have this typed
#include "/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a/extern/include/engine.h"
I have also tried with and without all sorts of things, but no avail.

Since MATLAB_R2012a is an application how does that change things?

Comment: @KevinShaffer Have you tried to add this folder to your include path using `-I`?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the simple solution, assuming that your matrices are kept in 3-dimmensional array:

Build a loop in C++, to save your matrices... Something like this:

```
ofstream arquivoOut0("myMatrices.dat");
  for(int m=0;m<numberMatrices;m++){ 
      for (int i=0; i< numberlines;i++){
           for(int j=0;j<numberColumns;j++)
               if(j!=numberColumns-1) arquivoOut0<< matrices[m][i][j] << "\t";
               else arquivoOut0<< matrices[m][i][j] << "\n";
           }
       }
  }
arquivoOut0.close();
```

Ok. You have saved your matrices in an ascii file! Now you have to read it in Matlab!

```
load myMatrices.dat

  for m=1:numberMatrices
      for i=1:numberLines
           for j=1:numberColumns
               myMatricesInMatlab(m,i,j)=myMatrices((m-1)*numberLines+i,j);
           end
       end
  end
```

Now, you can use the toolbox that you need:

```
for i=1:numberMatrices
    Apply the toolbox for myMatricesInMatlab(i,:,:);
end
```

I think it works, it the processing time is not an issue!